# Ajax is being called in Chrome but not IE

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, ajax, json, pnp

I'm using Ajax calls to pull in data for a table and I have successfully been able to pull in data for Chrome and everything shows up perfectly fine, but my table is not wanting to show up in IE at all and I don't know why.

Chrome:
[image]

In IE, it's not showing up at all.

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableExport/3.2.5/css/tableexport.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/3.0.0/fetch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sp-pnp-js/3.0.10/pnp.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/e9d941381475b5df8b7d7691013401e171014e89/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableExport/3.3.5/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>

<style>
.top {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.csv, .txt, .xls, .xlsx {
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
</style>

<div id="buttons" style="display: table">
<div id="title" style="width: 100%;"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
    "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HISC Franchise Information')/items?$top=1000&$orderby=Title&$select=Title,Franchises_x0020_with_x0020_Shar/Title,Franchise_x0020_Name,DMA/Title,City,State,Region,Stand_x0020_Alone_x0020_Franchis,Media_x0020_Specialist_x0028_s_x/Title,Primary_x0020_Contact,Key_x0020_Player_x0020_Email,Owner_x0020_Email,Franchise_x0020_Liason/Title&$expand=Franchises_x0020_with_x0020_Shar,DMA,Media_x0020_Specialist_x0028_s_x,Franchise_x0020_Liason&$filter=substringof('Peyton',Franchise_x0020_Liason/Title)";
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            onSuccess(data);
            ExportTable();
        }
    });

    function onSuccess(data) {
        var item = data.d.results;
        var tableContent = '<table id="TablePanel" border="1px;"><thead><tr><th>Franchise Number</th>' + '<th>Franchises with Shared Owner</th>' + '<th>Franchise Name</th>' + 
        '<th>DMA</th>' + '<th>City</th>' + '<th>State</th>' + '<th>Region</th>' + '<th>Stand Alone Franchise</th>' + '<th>Franchise Liason</th>' + '<th>Media Specialist(s)</th>' + '<th>Primary Contact</th>' + 
        '<th>Key Player Email</th>' + '<th>Owner Email</th>' + '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            tableContent += '<tr>'
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Title + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Franchises_x0020_with_x0020_Shar.results.map(r => r.Title).join('; ') + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Franchise_x0020_Name + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].DMA.results.map(r => r.Title).join('; ') + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].City + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].State + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Region + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Stand_x0020_Alone_x0020_Franchis + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Franchise_x0020_Liason.results.map(r => r.Title).join('; ') + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Media_x0020_Specialist_x0028_s_x.results.map(r => r.Title).join('; ') + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Primary_x0020_Contact + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Key_x0020_Player_x0020_Email + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + item[i].Owner_x0020_Email + '</td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
            tableContent += '</tbody></thead>';
        }
        $('#title').append(tableContent);
    }

    function ExportTable() {
        $("#buttons").tableExport({
            headings: true,
            footers: true,
            formats: ["xls", "csv", "txt"],
            fileName: "id",
            bootstrap: true,
            position: "top",
            ignoreRows: false,
            ignoreCols: false,
            ignoreCSS: ".tableexport-ignore"
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Does anyone know what might be preventing it? or someone that has had this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write which exactly error is showing up in IE, but based on the code I can see one thing that doesn't work in IE. That's the `arrow functions` syntax that you use when you call the `map` function.

Try changing the parameter you pass to the `map` function in all three instances from this:

```
results.map(r => r.Title).join('; ')
```

to this:

```
results.map(function(r) {return r.Title;}).join('; ')
```

Comment: Hey Damjan,

I ended up figured out the problem - When I transscripted my code to babel it now works, mysteriously.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents It works because Babel transpiles your ES6 code to be ES5 compliant. Arrow functions were introduced in ES6 and are not supported by Internet Explorer. So Babel "translates" them to the older standard in the way that Damjan wrote.

Comment: Ahh, that makes so much more sense! Thanks for clarifying that.